# JS: pin scroll between classic scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, gsap

I am quite new to JS and I try to make a pin scroll. However, I would like to put this pin scroll between two divs which have a normal scroll. I looked on the Internet, trying to modify what I found to make what I want to do. Here is what I've done with GSAP. Is there a solution that does not require any library?

Here is my code with GSAP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-basic" style="height: 1500px;">Some content</div>
    <div id="snap-scroll">
        <section id="1" class="page one">1</section>
        <section id="2" class="page two">2</section>
        <section id="3" class="page">3</section>
        <section id="4" class="page">4</section>
    </div>
    <div class="content-basic" style="height: 1500px;">Some content</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
    section.page {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: gray;
    }
</style>
<script>
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    gsap.to(window, {
        scrollTo: {y: document.querySelector('.two').offsetTop, autoKill: false},
        duration: 2,
        scrollTrigger: {
            start: "bottom bottom",
            markers: true,
            trigger: ".one"
        }
    });
</script>
```

It works but the "automatic" scroll is weird: it first goes to the top of the page before scrolling to the next page...